# Cuda: Using shared memory for counting elements

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu-shared-memory

After kernel calculations I have produced different values, ranging from 0 to 6399, that are stored in shared memory. I have 24336 blocks so 24336 instances of a `__shared__` array with size of 256. Each block array is filled with the calculated values in no particular order.

What I want is to count how many times there is a certain value in all of those block shared memories and that value should be the index of another array (that resides in global memory) and its respective value would be the number of times it has appeared.

In a modified shorter example with two blocks and a `__shared__ int array1[3]` and a `__device__ array2` I might have:

For `blockIdx.x=0`

```
array1[0]=10;
array1[1]=20;
array1[2]=30;
```

And in `blockIdx.x=1`

```
array1[0]=30;
array1[1]=0;
array1[2]=10;
```

And the result should be

```
array2[0]=1;   //value 0 has appeared one time
array2[10]=2;  //value 10 has appeared two times
array2[20]=1;  //value 20 has appeared one time
array2[30]=2;  //value 30 has appeared two times
```

How can this be done in parallel as much as possible?

**EDIT**:

From the answers that followed my question I found a lot of help about my problem.

Especially a code that generates any kind of histogram and takes as input any amount of bins and an array containing the bins. [Code: General purpose histogram](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/511531/code-general-purpose-histogram/)
I forgot about my initial plan and just created a `__global__` array and stored all the bins there.

In my case I used an array of 68000000 integers with bins ranging from 0 to 6399. It worked fine and I get a speedup so I forgot about my initial idea to store all the bins in shared memory and calculate the number of bins from there, but I'm not satisfied as much with the execution time and I'd like to try something else.

I was wondering if anyone has any idea about how to get back to my initial idea and what techniques should I use (i.e. exclusive scan etc.).

I remember a fellow stackoverflower had posted an answer with this but he deleted his post I think quite quickly, without me having time to look over it thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

I understand this problem to be the same as histogramming. A number of good solutions exist and can be googled, including [Nvidia's own sample](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/e612904184446c81e4d5beac8755081f9662cca0/Samples/2_Concepts_and_Techniques/histogram).

Particularly worth mentioning are these codes:

- [http://www.moderngpu.com/sort/hist.html (Wayback Machine)](https://web.archive.org/web/20111124025224/http://www.moderngpu.com/sort/hist.html)
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/code-general-purpose-histogram/25457
- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/fast-histogram-code-released-source-code-for-two-new-histogramming-methods/22186

Answer (score 2):

As near as I can tell this is just building a histogram.  While this method probably won't be fastest (unless maybe you are on Kepler K20) you could do something relatively simple at the end of your kernel (assuming your shared array1 is size 256 elements and you are launching at least 256 threads in a 1D threadblock):

```
if (threadIdx.x < 256)
  atomicAdd(&(array2[array1[threadIdx.x]]), 1);
```

(assumes compute capability 1.1 or better for [atomic function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions))